# Hide show div not working in two places based on separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using two div with same script in my page. The script was working for only one div. I copied the same script and trying edit for my new div but the second div affect the first div changes. Below script in my `main.js` file.

```
//first div

var $container = $('.cat-area .posts').isotope({
  itemSelector : '.itemat',
  isFitWidth: true
});

  $container.isotope({
    columnWidth: '.col-sm-3'
  });

$container.isotope({ filter: '.htileone' });

  // filter items on button click
$('#filter-tile').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});



 //second div
var $container1 = $('.hi .cat-area .posts').isotope({
  itemSelector : '.itmatmob',
  isFitWidth: true
});

  $container1.isotope({
    columnWidth: '.col-sm-3'
  });

$container1.isotope({ filter: '.htileone1' });

  // filter items on button click
$('#filter-tile-mob').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue1 = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container1.isotope({ filter: filterValue1 });
});
```

[my website link](http://orderonline.my/designer/alpha-tiles/homogeneous-tile.php)

Comment: can you share your HTML code?

Comment: You should refactor the code into a function and extract arguments and not copy the code.

Comment: @Tanmay As I mentioned the the my website link `homogeneous-tile.php`

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question, don't link off-site.

Comment: @H.B. can you assist how to do that? Do you any idea about this

Comment: I am referring to general skill that you should acquire if you do not have it. You can read about refactoring in various tutorials and books.

Comment: Okay. I will try to resolve this.

Comment: your website is showing `$` not define error in console. Try to correct that first (add jQuery library before current script code or check any jQuery files are conflicting with each other):- https://prnt.sc/iwxvto

Comment: Include your JS under **<head>** Tag or before your **<script>** tag

Comment: @John I have check your website code you are using the duplicate code in many places. i.e "Filter with size" you have declared that 2 times on your DOM which is not good practice.

Comment: @John  try to put all js files in `<head></head>` section and then try

Comment: @Tanmay I need use the option in multiple places. any idea.

Comment: Uploaded into `<head></head>`

Comment: @John Meaning you want to show filters in multiple places, Right? but POSTS should be in the one DIV.

Comment: No. Maintain the current view in my website . only prob if I click the first div the second div tiles also affected

Answer (score 0):

As per above chat with @John He wants filters on multiple places.

**Use classes in filters so that click function works of all filter buttons. **

HTML Sample code.

```
<div class="filter-tile-mob">
    <button class="btn btn-primary active1" data-filter=".htiletwo1"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i>Filter 2</button>

    <button class="btn btn-primary active1" data-filter=".htiletwo2"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i>Filter 2</button>

   <button class="btn btn-primary active1" data-filter=".htiletwo3"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i>Filter 3</button>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid no-gutter">
    <div class="posts">
       <div class="itemat htiletwo1 col-xs-12 itmatmob"></div>
      <div class="itemat htileone2 col-xs-12 itmatmob"></div>
      <div class="itemat htileone3 col-xs-12 itmatmob"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
var $container = $('.container-fluid .posts').isotope({
   itemSelector : '.itemat',
   isFitWidth: true,
   columnWidth: '.col-sm-3'
});
 // filter items on button click
$('.filter-tile-mob').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```